# Leaflet is not reading external geojson or JS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to build a Leaflet map with a geojson layer. The layer is a huge file, so I have a separate file with the geojson in the variable.

However, when I run the code, I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myLayer is not defined

```
<script src="leaflet/mygeofile.geojson"></script> <!-- or use leaflet-src.js -->

<script src="/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script> <!-- or use leaflet-src.js -->
<script src="/leaflet/leaflet_javascript.js"></script> <!-- or use leaflet-src.js -->

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {


    //Set attributes of map (location and zoom)
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    //Add base map layer, using a compatible source, with accesstoken/permissions
    //for more basemaps:  https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers 
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'your.mapbox.project.id',
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.public.access.token'
}).addTo(map);

//***********GEO JSON FILE IS CALLED RIGHT HERE*******************
L.geoJson(myLayer).addTo(map);
});


</script>
```

GEOJSON SAMPLE:

```
 myLayer=[{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": null, "description": null, "timestamp": null, "begin": null, "end": null, "altitudeMode": "relativeToGround", "tessellate": -1, "extrude": -1, "visibility": -1, "drawOrder": null, "icon": null, "STATEFP": "17", "COUNTYFP": "019", "TRACTCE": "005401", "BLKGRPCE": "2", "GEOID": "1701900540...........
}]}]
```

Comment: is `.geojson` a valid file extension? I would have thought you should be saving your data as a `.js` file

Comment: Yes, I believe it is. That's what QGIS saves it as automatically. Even so, I've tried changing the extension to json, and js and it still gives the same error. Also changing the extensions actually changed the structure of the data to be like json instead of geojson format.

Answer (score 0):

L.GeoJSON expects a Feature or FeatureCollection object, an array of Feature objects or null as the first parameter. Not an array containing  a FeatureCollection object. Strip the surrounding brackets (and it's good practice to declare a variable with the var keyword before you use it):

```
var myLayer = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
    "features": [{
         "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": null, "description": null, "timestamp": null, "begin": null, "end": null, "altitudeMode": "relativeToGround", "tessellate": -1, "extrude": -1, "visibility": -1, "drawOrder": null, "icon": null, "STATEFP": "17", "COUNTYFP": "019", "TRACTCE": "005401", "BLKGRPCE": "2", "GEOID": "1701900540...........
     }]
}
```

You're also missing a slash in the src attribute of your script tag. You can check if all your files are being loaded in the network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Change:

```
<script src="leaflet/mygeofile.geojson"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="/leaflet/mygeofile.geojson"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the error and no layer, after removing the brackets

Comment: Thanks, changed that, but still get the error. The file shows up in network tab in Inspect Element.

Comment: I put the geojson code in the same file as the rest of the javascript and removed the script call to the external geojson file.

Now there is an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

But it points to a line of code that doesn't exist (line 1492, but there are only 1300 lines) and when I click on the error in the console, the line/screen it links to is just empty

Comment: EDIT: Actually, the last error is because the copy/paste did not copy the full geojson. I think because the file is too large.

Comment: That's indeed on the "large" side. Perhaps you could look into TopoJSON for simplifying your collection: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson

Comment: I don't know. I will just have to recalculate my approach. When I try to convert using topojson, I get "Error: toString failed." I googled that error and looks like it's due to the file size.